# Data simulation according to specific rules in R

Tags: r

I need help simulating a dataset.

It is supposed to simulate all possible outcomes on a signal detection theory task (participants are presented with trials and have to decide whether or not they detected given signal).  Now, I need a dataset of all possible values for varying number of trials.

Say, there are 6 trials, 5 with the signal present, 5 with the signal absent. I am only interested in correct detections (hits) and false alarms (Type I errors). A participant can correctly detect between 1 (I don't need 0's) and 5 and make the same number of false alarms. With all possible combinations, that would be dataset containing two variables with 5^2 cases each. To make things more complicated, even the number of trials is variable. The number of both signal and non-signal trials can vary between 1 and 20 but the total number of trials cannot be less than 3 (either 1 S trial and 2 Non-S trials, or the other way around). And for each possible combination of trials, there is a group of possible combinations of hits and false alarms.

What I need is a dataset with 5 variables (total N, N of S trials, N of Non-S trials, N of Hits, and N of False Alarms) with all the possible values.

**EXAMPLE**
Here are all possible data for total N of 4. Note that Signal + Noise = N_total and that N_Hit seq(1:Signal) and N_FA seq(1:Noise)

```
N_total   Signal   Noise  N_Hit  N_FA
  4         1        3      1     1
  4         1        3      1     2
  4         1        3      1     3
  4         2        2      1     1
  4         2        2      1     2
  4         2        2      2     1
  4         2        2      2     2
  4         3        1      1     1
  4         3        1      2     1
  4         3        1      3     1
```

I'm an R novice so any help at all would be much appreciated!

Hope the description is clear.

Comment: The description is confusing me.  It would be much easier to understand if you gave a few sample lines of the data you are trying to produce.  This sounds like an "all permutations" problem, but without more detail about the constraints of the data and the resulting data structure, I'm not sure we can help you.  Please update your question to be a bit more explicit.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is this maybe a little clearer?

Comment: Yes.  You'll notice it also elicited an answer, so you know your edit worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a function, which uses the number of trials as parameter.

```
myfunc <- function(n) {

  # create a data frame of all combinations
  grid <- expand.grid(rep(list(seq_len(n - 1)), 4))

  # remove invalid combinations (keep valid ones)
  grid <- grid[grid[3] <= grid[1] &         # number of hits <= number of signals
               grid[4] <= grid[2] &         # false alarms <= noise
               (grid[1] + grid[2]) == n , ] # signal and noise sum to total n

  # remove signal and noise > 20
  grid <- grid[!rowSums(grid[1:2] > 20), ]

  # sort rows
  grid <- grid[order(grid[1], grid[3], grid[4]), ]

  # add total number of trials
  res <- cbind(n, grid)

  # remove row names, add column names and return the object
  return(setNames("rownames<-"(res, NULL),
                  c("N_total", "Signal", "Noise", "N_Hit", "N_FA"))) 


}
```

Use the function:

```
> myfunc(4)
   N_total Signal Noise N_Hit N_FA
1        4      1     3     1    1
2        4      1     3     1    2
3        4      1     3     1    3
4        4      2     2     1    1
5        4      2     2     1    2
6        4      2     2     2    1
7        4      2     2     2    2
8        4      3     1     1    1
9        4      3     1     2    1
10       4      3     1     3    1
```

How to apply this function to the values 3-40:

```
lapply(3:40, myfunc)
```

This will return a list of data frames.

Comment: That is fantastic, thank you! I'm still trying to get my head around what you did there.
If I could ask two more things: Is there a way how to set the maximum value of signal and noise to 20 so that when I do myfunc(40) it only returns values for Signal and Noise <= 20?
Secondly, is there a way to run myfunc(3 to 40) in one go?
Thanks a million!

Comment: @user2062339 Why do you want to run the function with values from 3-40  although the maximum value should be 20?

Comment: So I managed to restrict the maximum value, but I still don't know how to run myfunc(3 to 40) in one go...

Comment: sorry for not explaining my self sufficiently. it is the number of signal and noise trials that should be restricted to 20 (and I have already done that), not the total N. That means that myfunc(40) would have only the value of 20 in the Signal and Noise columns. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user2062339 How can the sum of signal and noise trials be lower than the absolute number of trials?

Comment: It cannot. For my func(40), S = 20 & Noise = 20. For myfunc(39), S = 19 & Noise = 20 OR S = 20 & Noise = 19 and so on...

I did that by editing your script thus:

  # remove invalid combinations (keep valid ones)
grid <- grid[grid[3] <= grid[1] & grid[1] <= 20 &                 grid[4] <= grid[2] & grid[2] <= 20 &
(grid[1] + grid[2]) == n , ]

Comment: You're a legend! Thank you.